# Ubuntu variant with Flash

Tags: flash, live-cd

Is there a Ubuntu variant that comes with flash pre-installed? I used to use Lubuntu, as chromium used to have it, but now it doesn't work. The reason I want it pre-installed is that I use it a lot as a live CD.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, but that's the same as trying to install flash.

Comment: Ubuntu errh.. Canonical can't included Flash on the Ubuntu Live CD because it's proprietary software by Adobe, the same goes for MP3 decoding. You may just want to redo the LiveCD with persistence active and just install flash or install Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to make changes persist that are made in a live session. It relies on a mechanism that searches all drives for a filesystem with the label "casper-rw". It will mount that filesystem as a writeable overlay over the non-persistant filesystem (this is called a union mount).

There are multiple ways on how to go about this. If you want to continue booting from a CD, then you can plug in a USB stick (before booting the live session, not after -- it must be present while the live session is booting).

Or you could make the USB stick contain two partitions, one with the bootable live system and a second partition with the "casper-rw" filesystem.

The details can be found here (read them in this order, the first article seems more to the point):

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Comment: Or.. or use Unetbootin, add space for persistence and save yourself of messing with file systems ;)

Comment: Unetbootin is one of the options in the second URL. It might be the preferred option for many. So it's a good point.